# Could not use Derby plugin on Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, derby

I have downloaded the latest stable version of Derby:

http://db.apache.org/derby/releases/release-10.8.2.2.cgi

Installed it to the Eclipse plugins folder, as suggested.

Then I am trying to use the following instruction:

http://db.apache.org/derby/integrate/plugin_help/start_toc.html

The third step fails:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.derby.drda.NetworkServerControl
```

Googled, but cannot find the info how to solve this problem. Any ideas?

Comment: For Derby plugin issues, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12645223/is-it-possible-to-use-derby-from-apache-in-eclipse-now-that-they-stopped-develop?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this problem by making a **new clean project** instead of using an existing project!

Answer (score 1):

org.apache.derby.drda.NetworkServerControl is in the derbynet.jar file that came with your Derby distribution.

Answer (score 0):

download apache derby bin distribution and unzip in any directory
set environment variable with name DERBY_HOME to your directory of derby upto \bin path
now in your project right click and set apache derby nature
Now you can start and stop apache derby from eclipse ide

Answer (score 0):

Add `Derbynet.jar`in reference libraries from `org.apache.derby.core_10.8.2` and now start derby network server.It should work.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the website http://db.apache.org/derby/releases/release-10.1.3.1.html
Below you will see the Eclipse plugin

```
derby_core_plugin_10.1.3.zip [PGP] [MD5]
derby_ui_plugin_1.1.0.zip [PGP] [MD5]
```

download these two zip files and unzip.
Go to Eclipse folder in the Eclipse folder u will see plugins folder put into three folders

```
org.apache.derby.core_10.1.3
org.apache.derby.plugin.doc_1.1.0`
org.apache.derby.plugin.ui_1.1.
```

Then open Eclipse and create a Java project.
Right click on the Java project you will see Apache Derby-->add Apache Derby nature click on that
You will get Apache libraries, you can start or create database or table whatever you want this will work fine.